Close form of $\int_a^b x^n \sqrt{(b-x)(x-a)}dx$
I am interested in the integrals of form
$$I_n=\int_a^b x^n \sqrt{(b-x)(x-a)}dx$$
with $b>a>0$.
I have already derived the close form solutions for the first few integrals below
\begin{align}
& I_0=\int_a^b \sqrt{(b-x)(x-a)}dx=\frac\pi8(b-a)^2 \\
& I_1=\int_a^b x\sqrt{(b-x)(x-a)}dx=\frac\pi{16}(b-a)^2 (a+b)\\
& I_2=\int_a^b x^2\sqrt{(b-x)(x-a)}dx=\frac\pi{128}(b-a)^2 (5a^2+6ab+5b^2)\\
\end{align}
I am wondering if there is a systematic derivation that leads to a generalized close form solution for $I_n$.

Substitute $x = a \cos^2 \theta + b \sin^2 \theta$.
Then, $$I_n = \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} (a \cos^2 \theta + b \sin^2 \theta)^n \left(\sqrt{(b-a)\sin^2 \theta (b-a)\cos^2\theta}\right)(b-a)2\sin\theta\cos\theta d\theta$$
$$=2(b-a)^2 \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \sum_{p=0}^n {n\choose p} a^p b^{n-p} \cos^{2p + 2}(\theta) \sin^{2n + 2-2p}(\theta) d\theta$$
$$= (b-a)^2 \sum_{p=0}^n {n\choose p}  a^p b^{n-p} B\left(\frac{2p+3}{2},\frac{2n-2p+3}{2}\right)$$
$$=(b-a)^2 \sum_{p=0}^n {n\choose p}  a^p b^{n-p} \frac{\Gamma(p + \frac{3}{2})\Gamma(n-p+\frac{3}{2})}{\Gamma{(n+3)}}  $$
$$ = \frac{\pi (b-a)^2}{4^{n+1} (n+2)(n+1)} \sum_{p=0}^n a^p b^{n-p} \frac{(2p+1)! (2n-2p+1)!}{(p!(n-p)!)^2}$$
Some examples:
$I_2 = \frac{\pi (b-a)^2}{4^3\cdot 12} (b^2\cdot \frac{5!1!}{(2!)^2} + ab \frac{3!3!}{(1!1!)^2} + a^2\cdot \frac{5!1!}{(2!)^2}) = \frac{\pi(b-a)^2}{128}(5a^2+6ab+5b^2)$
$I_3 = \frac{\pi (b-a)^2}{4^4 \cdot 5 \cdot 4}(a^3 \frac{7!}{(3!^2)}+ a^2 b \frac{3!5!}{2!2!} + ab^2 \frac{3!5!}{2!2!} + b^3 \frac{7!}{(3!^2)}) = \frac{\pi (b-a)^2}{256}(7a^3 + 9a^2b + 9ab^2 + 7b^3)$
$I_4 = \frac{\pi(b-a)^2}{1024}(21a^4+28a^3b+30a^2b^2+28ab^3+21b^4)$

Define $g(x) = \sqrt{(b-x)(x-a)}$ and  $$I_{n,m} = \int_{a}^{b} x^{n} (x-a)^m g(x)dx.$$
Then we obtain the recurrence relation $$ I_{n,m} = \int_{a}^{b} x^{n-1} ((x-a) + a) (x-a)^m g(x)dx = I_{n-1,m+1}+aI_{n-1,m}, \\ =I_{n-2,m+2}+2aI_{n-2,m+1}+a^2I_{n-2,m}$$
where we keep reducing until we reach the terms involving $I_{0,m}$ for natural numbers $m$. This integral can be evaluated exactly as follows: Define $h=b-a$,  $$I_{0,m} = \int_a^{b} (x-a)^{m+\frac{1}{2}} (b-x)^{\frac{1}{2}}dx  \overset{a+h\sin^2{t}}{=} 2h^{m+2}\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\sin^{2m+2}{(t)}\cos^{2}{(t)}dt \\ = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}\frac{h^{m+2}}{(m+2)!}\Gamma\left(m+\frac{3}{2}\right) = \frac{h}{m+2}\left(\frac{2m+1}{2}\right)I_{0,m-1}. $$
This relation can be used to compute the integrals. $$ I_{0,0} = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}\frac{h^{2}}{2}\Gamma\left(\frac{3}{2}\right) = \frac{\pi}{8}h^2,\quad I_{0,1}  = \frac{h}{2}I_{0,0} = \frac{\pi}{16}h^3 \\ I_{0,2} = \frac{5h}{8}I_{0,1} = \frac{5\pi}{128}h^4,\quad I_{0,3} = \frac{7h}{10}I_{0,2} = \frac{7\pi}{256}h^5,\\ I_{1,1} = I_{0,2}+aI_{0,1} =  \frac{5\pi}{128}h^4 + \frac{\pi}{16}h^3a.$$
We have $I_0 = I_{0,0} = \frac{\pi}{8}h^2$, $$ I_{1,0} = I_{0,1}+aI_{0,0} = \frac{\pi}{16}h^3+\frac{\pi}{8}h^2a,\\
I_{2,0} = I_{0,2}+2aI_{0,1}+a^2I_{0,0} = \frac{5\pi}{128}h^4 + \frac{\pi}{8}h^3a+\frac{\pi}{8}h^2a^2, \\ I_{3,0} = I_{1,2}+2aI_{1,1}+a^2I_{1,0} =  \frac{7\pi}{256}h^5 + \frac{15\pi}{128}h^4a + \frac{3\pi}{16}h^3a^2+\frac{\pi}{8}h^2a^3. $$

how did u obtain the recurrence relation?

By adding and subtracting $a$. $$ \int_a^b x^{n-1} \cdot x \cdot (x-a)^m g(x)dx =  \int_a^b x^{n-1} \cdot ((x-a)+a) \cdot (x-a)^m g(x)dx $$

and then after that?

and then multiplying the terms together $$ \int_{a}^b x^{n-1}(x-a)^{m+1}g(x)dx+a \int_{a}^b x^{n-1}(x-a)^{m}g(x)dx = I_{n-1,m+1}+a\cdot I_{n-1,m}$$

There is an antiderivative in terms of the Appell hypergeometric function of two variables.
For the definite integral, the result is given in terms of the Gaussian hypergeometric function
$$\frac{\pi \,  a^n}{4 (n+1) (n+2)} \big(a(a+b)A_n + b (b (2 n+1)-a (2 n+3))B_n\big)$$ where
$$A_n=\,_2F_1\left(-\frac{1}{2},-n;1;1-\frac{b}{a}\right)$$
$$B_n=\,_2F_1\left(+\frac{1}{2},-n;1;1-\frac{b}{a}\right)$$
Let $t=1-\frac{b}{a}$; if $n$ is a non negative integer, $A_n$ and $B_n$ are trivial polynomials of degree $n$ in $t$.
You can use this paper for recursive formulas.

Observing that
$$(b-x)(x-a)=-x^2+(a+b)x-ab=\left(\frac{b-a}{2}  \right)^2-\left(x-\frac{a+b}{2}  \right)^2$$
Let $x-\frac{b+a}{2}=\frac{b-a}{2}\sin\theta   $ , then
$$
\begin{aligned}
\int_a^b x^n \sqrt{(b-x)(x-a)}dx& =\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\left(\frac{b-a}{2} \sin \theta+\frac{b+a}{2}\right)^n\left(\frac{b-a}{2}\right)^2 \cos ^2 \theta d \theta \\
& =\left(\frac{b-a}{2}\right)^{n+2} \int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\left(\sin \theta+\frac{b+a}{b-a}\right)^n \cos ^2 \theta d \theta \\
& =\left(\frac{b-a}{2}\right)^{n+2} \int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\binom{n}{k} \sin ^k \theta\left(\frac{b+a}{b-a}\right)^{n -k} \cos ^2 \theta d \theta \\
& =\left(\frac{b-a}{2}\right)^{n+2} \sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}\left(\frac{b+a}{b-a}\right)^{n-k} \int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \sin ^k \theta \cos ^2 \theta d \theta \\
& =\left(\frac{b-a}{2}\right)^{n+2} \sum_{k=0}^{[n/2]}\binom{n}{2 k}\left(\frac{b+a}{b-a}\right)^{n-2 k} \cdot2\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \sin ^{2 k} \theta \cos ^2 \theta d \theta\\&=\left(\frac{b-a}{2}\right)^{n+2} \sum_{k=0}^{[n / 2]}\binom{n}{2 k}\left(\frac{b+a}{b-a}\right)^{n-2 k} B\left(k+\frac{1}{2}, \frac{3}{2}\right) \\
& =\left(\frac{b-a}{2}\right)^{n+2} \sum_{k=0}^{[n / 2]}\binom{n}{2 k}\left(\frac{b+a}{b-a}\right)^{n-2 k} \frac{\sqrt{\pi} \Gamma\left(k+\frac{1}{2}\right)}{2 \Gamma\left(\frac{k}{2}+2\right)}
\end{aligned}
$$
